# How to create standing water with a Mantaflow fluid sim?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I've been trying to work with smaller-scale Mantaflow simulations. In this case, I have a small amount of water dripping from a pipe/faucet, and I want it to form a puddle on the plane under the pipe. I have no problem creating the water, the problem is it just disappears or keeps moving infinitely, rather than settling into a puddle. Adding surface tension just makes it break apart more, and viscosity messes up the overall behaviour of the fluid. Is this even possible? It's an effect that's important for many projects I have in mind.

Here is my .blend file, I couldn't figure out how to upload it here other than using Drive, sorry: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oEYE50GIW7_3Fw0bhpzPgIbKOH8q9jiQ/view?usp=sharing

And here's a stock photo I found of the result I'm looking for, which is what I mean by standing water:

[image]